# Setting emacs font under windows

Tags: windows, emacs, fonts

I'm having trouble to change the font for my emacs configuration.
I've tried using set-default-font, and managed to tab to my desired font, however, some elements are still rendered as the old font (ie python's class names and function names)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[set-default-font](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/old/faq5.html) is really old, and has been deprecated in Emacs 23 in favor of its new name set-frame-font (which isn't much better).  The current Emacs manual [suggests several ways to set the default font](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fonts.html), but I'll assume you've found those already, seeing as you've tried set-default-font...

The elisp code I use is actually different from all the methods suggested there:

```
;; [in .emacs]
;; Use 10-pt Consolas as default font
(set-face-attribute 'default nil
                    :family "Consolas" :height 100)
```

set-face-attribute seems to stick better than set-default-font; at least it seems to use Consolas consistently even in things like Python class and function names.

Comment: I was suggested to use set-frame-font over the IRC, and the reason my fonts got messed up is due to color-theme, apparently, the theme I used was a little bugish...

Answer (score 1):

`M-x customize-face default` will let you customize the default font.

If some things are still rendered in a font you don't like, then position your cursor to be over the offending text and type `M-x customize-face`; the face that your cursor is over will be the default one to customize.